# Click div to add padding to another div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am wondering if I can use jquery so that when I click on a fixed `div` it adds padding to another `div`. For the example below, I would like to add `40px` of padding to the top of `div2` once I click `div1`, and when clicked again I would like to revert to the original amount of padding `(20px)`.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/p9LfkLsd/1/

html:

```
<div id="div1">The Pusher</div>
<div id="div2">Push me down!</div>
```

css:

```
#div1{
position:fixed;
background-color:red;
color:white;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#div2{
padding-top:20px;
background-color:blue;
color:white;
width:100px
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code in jquery

```
$('#div1').on('click', function(){
    var padding = $('#div2').css('padding-top');
    var newPadding = (padding=='20px')?'40px':'20px';
    $('#div2').css('padding-top',newPadding);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/p9LfkLsd/2/)

Comment: @paulj just accept the answer if it solved your question. This will help future viewers.

Comment: yup was just waiting for it to let me

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var defaultPadding="20px";
$("#div1").click(function(){
    var padding=$("#div2").css("padding-top");
    if(padding!="40px"){
         $("#div2").css("padding-top","40px");
    }else{
         $("#div2").css("padding-top",defaultPadding);
    }
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/p9LfkLsd/1/

Comment: I wonder why my jsfiddle don't have update button. The same as yours? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to toggle the padding.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/p9LfkLsd/1/)

JS

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
    $('#div2').toggleClass('addPadding');
});
```

CSS

```
.addPadding {
    padding-top:40px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").click(function(){
    var lastpad = $("#div2").css("padding-top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    var addpad = 40;
    var newpad = parseInt(lastpad) + addpad;
    $("#div2").css("padding-top", newpad+"px");
})
```

If needed for future use. [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lgnHc)